# Azure Notification Hub: The supplied notification payload is invalid

Tags: azure, notifications, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to send a JSON notification to APNS and when I try to send it I'm getting 400 Bad Request with the error message:

`The supplied notification payload is invalid.`

Here is my Notification JSON:

`{"uri":"myApp://test","type":"test_push","badge":1,"content-available":1}`

I create the notification like this:

`notif = new AppleNotification(json);`

I'm sending the notification:

`client.SendNotificationAsync(notif, "myTag")`

After that, I'm getting the error. The content type is `application/xml` by default, after I got the error, I've started setting the content type to `application/json` but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** My hub and certificates are installed correctly; I can send a successful test notification through Azure Portal.

Comment: Can, can you confirm you've uploaded the certificate?

Comment: @VivienChevallier yes, and I can send a test notification from Azure Portal successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can,

Your payload is malformed, please try with the following:

```
{"aps":{"uri":"myApp://test","type":"test_push","badge":1,"content-available":1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

After playing with the test push sending on Azure Portal, I've discovered the problem myself: Notification Hub wasn't accepting the JSON if it wasn't already wrapped in `aps` object. I've changed the JSON to be sent as:

`{aps: {"uri":"myApp://test","type":"test_push","badge":1,"content-available":1} }`

and now it's working. I thought it was auto wrapping, but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters using \. See in example below I have used double quote for word Hub which escape using \.

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Notification \\\"Hub\\\" test notification"}}
```